# Imported library is marked as an error right after i close propperties

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library

So, I've recently started having some weird errors when I'm about to import the android support library v7 using eclipse, I follow the steps on the android site and everything is working fine. I am working towards 4.0.3 so I changed the target SDK on the v7 library to 4.0.3 and built it before i exported the jars. On my project properties everything looks great:

[Dropbox image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5203120/Sk%C3%A4rmklipp1.PNG)

But when I apply the settings, close the dialog and re-open it without doing anything else it looks like this:

[second dropbox image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5203120/Sk%C3%A4rmklipp2.PNG)

I've tried reinstalling the library and clean and build several times but i still get the same wierd error. Also, when i hover over the apperantly faulty library there is no error mentioned.

Comment: Hi Simon, this problem occurs when the library you want import is on different partition, eg. F:, and the main project is on other one, eg. C:

Comment: Thanks :D 1 min fix for an hour-long problem xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy your project and support library to workspace using eclipse. Basically they both should be in the same folder.